# How to use basic logical symbols

Tags: logic

I have a question about basic logical symbols.

You can only use these symbols and I am trying to use them for this question, where $x \in \mathbb R$:

$⇒$, $=$, $⇔$

$a)$ $1 < x$ symbol $1 ≤ x$

$b)$ $x < 0$ symbol $0 < x^2$

$c)$ $0 < x^2$ symbol $x ≠ 0$

My answers:

$a)$ it can't be $⇔$  because you can't go from $1 ≤ x$ to $1 < x$ and they are not exactly the same so it  must be $⇒$

$b)$ is $⇒$ as well because if $x = -1$ or any negative number it will translate to positive in $0 < x^2$ and because in the first one it is required to be $x < 0$ it cant be $0$. $⇔$ cant be used because $0 < x^2$, $x$ can be positive but it has to be negative to apply to $x < 0$

$c)$ here I am not that sure, but I think it should be $⇔$ because it works from both sides

Comment: For (c), do you mean "$x^2<0$ symbol $0\neq 0$"?

Comment: or possibly $x \ne 0$ instead of $0 \ne 0$?

Comment: yeah sry clumsy mistake on my part

Comment: Well, good job! You got them all correct. (Also note that $=$ is not a logic symbol.)

Comment: The second one could also be $=$, i.e., $x < 0 = 0 < x^2$. But I'm guessing $=$ is a typo? Is it supposed to be $\Leftarrow$?

Comment: you mean in my description of the question I just looked at the question it is this symbols $⇒$, $=$, $⇔$

Comment: That's curious. If it's not a typo, then it's a valid answer to (b). It's different from the other symbols in that it's only linking the zeroes ($0=0$), whereas the other symbols are linking whole statements, i.e., $(1<x) \implies (1 \le x)$.

Comment: so $=$ is a valid answer to b ?

Comment: = is not a valid answer to b. Consider the case where x=1. Then x<0 is false, but 0<x^2 is true.

Comment: ok so would you consider my answers correct then ?

Comment: All of your answers are correct.